# Javascript -- Changes in state under Child not persisting in Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

Hi (: I've been trying to employ a system of child-parent communication to ensure that changes I make in the child are shown in the parent. More specifically, in one of the pages of my React app, I want to have a number of 'Switch' objects that I want to be able to toggle on/off, and have these changes persist across different pages. These are the steps I've followed:

1. create a state in my parent:

   ```
   class dashboard extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.updateObject.bind(this);
   }
   state = {
       test_dictionary: {'test': false}
   };
   ```
2. define a function inside the parent that updates the state described above.

   ```
   updateObject(current_key) {
       var new_state = Object.assign({}, this.state.test_dictionary);
       new_state[current_key] = !new_state[current_key]; // I want to flip the boolean when clicked
       this.setState({test_dictionary: new_state});
   }
   ```
3. I then pass the state and the function (shown above) from the parent, to the child.

   ```
   <childView test_dictionary={this.state.test_dictionary} updateObject={this.updateObject}/>
   ```
4. Finally, once I'm inside the child , I try to use the function and the state that is passed in to update the dictionary in the parent state every time a Switch object within the  is changed.

   ```
   <Switch 
       checked={this.props.test_dictionary['test']} 
       onChange={this.props.updateObject.bind('test')}
   />
   ```

However, this isn't doing what I would expect it to do. I've tried reading through numerous different examples of how to set up child-parent communication, and I thought this follows it quite closely. The error I"m getting when I try to click the Switch object is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateObject' of undefined
at String.handleSelectionChange (childView?9911:28)
at String.handleSelectionChange (createPrototypeProxy.js?9d62b87:44)
at Switch.setChecked (Switch.js?bc7e1ee:54)
at toggle (Switch.js?bc7e1ee:105)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js?c23a69d:69)
at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js?46a03e1:85)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js?46a03e1:105)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js?2c8fe93:43)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js?2c8fe93:54)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I would appreciate any help you could provide!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is the cause, but it could be because `bind` returns a new function, whose `this` context is set to whatever argument you pass it. So when you do this:

```
<Switch 
    checked={this.props.test_dictionary['test']} 
    onChange={this.props.updateObject.bind('test')}
/>
```

`updateObject` is running with the context of `'test'`. When I need to call a parent's callback prop from a child, I usually do it like this:

```
<Switch 
    checked={this.props.test_dictionary['test']} 
    onChange={() => {this.props.updateObject('test')}}
/>
```

Note the arrow function in `onChange`. This way we can create a new function to call the callback prop correctly, but pass it whatever parameter we want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! I changed it to what you suggested, and now the error is: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_dictionary' of undefined` instead of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateObject' of undefined`. From this, I'm hypothesizing that within my `updateObject` function, it can't reach the `this.state.test_dictionary` that I'm trying to access? Do you have any further suggestions? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but after you've done what jered said, and you're getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_dictionary' of undefined` I would try to change `updateObject`to an arrow function as when it is not an arrow function, `this` isn't necessarily referring to the `this`you are thinking about.

Try changing the function to this:

```
updateObject = (current_key) => {
    var new_state = Object.assign({}, this.state.test_dictionary);
    new_state[current_key] = !new_state[current_key]; // I want to flip the boolean when clicked
    this.setState({test_dictionary: new_state});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have placed state in a very strange place. It would cause it to always end up as undefined since it was not in the actual scope of the component.

```
class dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         test_dictonary: { test: false }
      };
      this.updateObject.bind(this);
    }

    updateObject(current_key) {
       const new_key = !this.state.test_dictonary[current_key];
       this.setState({test_dictionary: new_key});
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <childView test_dictionary={this.state.test_dictionary} updateObject={this.updateObject}/>
      )
    }
}
```

And do this on the switch to prevent funny binding from happening that is the source of your original error.

```
<Switch 
    checked={this.props.test_dictionary['test']}} 
    onChange={() => { this.props.updateObject('test'); }}
/>
```